# VBA excel code to delete the rows if N/A is found

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to find the `N/A` cells in the entire columns and then delete the entire row if `N/A` is found. I found this VBA code,  but it just doesn't work for me because it selects only one column. Please help (I am working on around 300000 rows in Excel Mac 2011)

```
Sub DeleteBlankARows() 
    With Application 
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual 
        .ScreenUpdating = False 
        Dim r As Long 
        For r = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1 
            If Cells(r, 11) = "" Then Rows(r).Delete 
        Next r 
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 
        .ScreenUpdating = True 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (tested on Windows XP / Excel 2007 but it should work on Mac / Office 2011):

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteNARows()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        For iCol = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            For r = Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(r, iCol)) Then Rows(r).Delete
            Next r
        Next iCol
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that you can (and probably have to) change the column where you want to check fot `#N/A` at the begining of the code

Comment: Thank you! but how can I make it runs automatically and checks all the columns?? as I have till UH column!

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I tried this edited code and it says "Excel cannot calculate a formula"

Comment: did it work the previous version? I think you might have a [circular reference](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/09/16/excel-circular-references/) when the code deleted the rows. We can remove alerts (i will edit my code) but this will not solve the issue at last

Comment: @JMax what if I do not want to delete the entire row? I just want to delete the items that are before the #N/A Ie: abc abc abc #N/A, I want to delete the 3 abc away

Comment: @user1204868: you can change the `Rows(r).Delete` part to whatever you want to clear. You can have a try and ask a new question if you can't succeed

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use `Find` to quickly test what cells were `NA()` (I have assumed your are testing for `=NA()` as formula cells - I can update if they are, or also can be text)

This code uses `SpecialCells` to search only error values.

```
Sub GetNA()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim strFA As String

On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No NA() cells"
    Exit Sub
End If

With rng1
    Set rng2 = .Find("=NA()", LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
        strFA = rng2.Address
        Set rng3 = rng2.EntireRow
        Do
            Set rng2 = .FindNext(rng2)
            Set rng3 = Union(rng3, rng2.EntireRow)
        Loop While Not rng2 Is Nothing And rng2.Address <> strFA
    End If
    If Not rng3 Is Nothing Then rng3.Delete
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: nice one too. This could be faster if there aren't too many #N/A but a large range of cells to check. Yet, I've read that [`find` seems to be quite slow](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/)

Comment: @JMax that is a good link from Charles. But as the article states, Find is the way to go for a multi-column search (and as an aside can handle partial matches, case sensitivity , format matching etc - which makes it more versatile than the other methods). Although for a single column search AutoFilter is a notable exception from the article